# What is industry best practice for using Target="_blank" inside of an authenticated site?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, https, secure-coding

I have an authenticated site, where inside the site, I am able to send messages to my users. While logged into the secured site, i have integration that allows the user to roam the site within the user portal and as well the public site, without losing a secured connection. I have a link that goes to a PDF, and have added Target="_blank", so that the user can click it, view the PDF and not leave the site to view the PDF.

When the user clicks on the PDF, they are prompted a messaging, saying you are leaving the secured site to view this PDF, even though the secure connection in the existing window still exists.

What is best practices from an user experience perspective? Was is correct to have the PDF open in a new tab/window while keeping the existing tab open with the secured site?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to speak to the "Industry best practice" aspect of the question, but if you want to avoid the "leaving secure site" warning, you can link to the PDF over `https://` instead of `http://`. If the PDF is hosted elsewhere and not available over `https://` you may need to save it to your server.

One trick I've found is that if you skip the http: or https: part of the link URL completely and just start it with `//www.example.com...` then the browser will request the link over the same protocol that linking page was served over.

Comment: Thanks, I will note that in the future!